# Cannot connect to my edmx with my data context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, dbcontext

I've not used VS MVC for a while but I'm writing a project which requires connecting to a Sql database which I've installed as an edmx file SwitchDB.edmx in my DAL folder. In the past I've set up my data context file which I then use to reference the data in my controller, the model help me to order the data in the correct way.
This is how my data context file looks

```
namespace Switches.DAL
{
    public class SwitchContext : DbContext
    {
        public SwitchContext()
           : base("DefaultConnection")
        { }
        public DbSet<Switch_List> SwitchList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've set up the "DefaultConnection" in my Web.config under connectionStrings and my model Switch_List.cs has the file settings. When I declare the DB context in my controller as below

```
private SwitchContext db = new SwitchContext();
```

Then I would expect to reference the SwitchContext to get my data, like this

```
var switches= db.SwitchList .ToList();
```

However, when I run the project and reference db in debug I get the following error message 'the function evaluation requires all threads to run'. The DB context SwitchContext is clearly not getting access to the Switch.edmx so what am I forgetting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, but you should see the connection properties using an IDE button (to re-evaluate the expression).

[image]

However, when you get to the part of `db.SwitchList.ToList()` does it generate any exceptions?

Comment: I have the same message for my whole file, how did you fix it?

Comment: The error I'm getting is 'db.Switch_List.local' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException'

Comment: I remember that I had several projects in the same solution, I was using a connection string from another project, I changed it, the same message came out but when I pressed the re-evaluate button all the properties of the context came out and it worked correctly. When you press the button you get?

Comment: Can you publish the code of the `Switch_List` object?